# Inspiron n5030 touchpad doesn't work until after windows login

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I'm working on an Inspiron n5030 running Windows 7. The touchpad does not respond at the Windows login screen but the keyboard does. After I login, the touchpad functions normally.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The mouse does work in bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the ALPS touchpad driver and re-install the newest version.

- Open Device Manager
- Locate and right click the ALPS touchpad driver and select 'Properties'
- Click the 'Driver' tab and press 'Uninstall'
- Accept the option to delete the file from the system
- Restart your computer
- Update your ALPS Touchpad driver to the [latest version available](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=VN4YK&FileId=2731097271&productCode=inspiron-15-n5030&urlProductCode=False) from Dell. Download the file to your desktop and then:

  `1.Double-click the new icon on the desktop labeled R274721.exe.`

  2.The Self-Extracting window appears and prompts you to extract or 
  unzip to C:\DELL\DRIVERS\R274721. Write down this path so the executable (I.e. 
  Setup.exe) file can be found later.

  3.The Self-Extractor window appears.

  4.Click OK.

  5.After completing the file extraction, if the Self-Extractor 
  window is still open, close it.

  6.Click the Start button and then click Run.

  7.Type C:\DELL\DRIVERS\R274721 in the Open textbox and then click OK.

  8.Follow the on-screen installation instructions.

Comment: No help.  Same version was already installed.

Comment: Josh, even if its the same version it's worth uninstalling your current driver (deleting driver in device manager->reboot) and re-installing this one (new hardware->autodetect->c:\dell\drivers\r274721) if you haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I just deleted the driver form device manager(and chose to remove from system), rebooted, and it works.  I did start to reinstall from the link you posted, but it still said "This is the same version already installed.  Anyway, it works and I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer as correct.  Thanks for your help!